# GPIO 3.3 V signal still readable after inputting high resistance values

Tags: raspbian, gpio, python, voltage, signal

I recently obtained a raspberry pi 4 (8GB) and I am trying to understand the GPIO behavior and ran into an event that I don't understand.

I have set-up a simple script that allows pin 36 (GPIO 16) to output random high and low signals at a frequency of 2 Hz. The signal is received by pin 16 (GPIO 23). A direct connection reads the signal well, as expected, but increasing the resistance (up to 2M ohms) had no effect on the voltage received by pin 16, which I would expect the signal to be unreadable at this resistance level.

There is probably a simple answer but it will still be appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Imagine that resistance impedes current (causing "friction" and energy loss aka voltage drop), however it takes very little current to read a voltage. In fact you only need to charge up the very small capacitance of an input pin. So as long as you are not changing values too quickly, you will always be able to read the value up to a very large series resistance. To put it an equivalent way, the "input impedance" of a GPIO input pin is very high and external impedance will not have a significant impact on digital readings until it is larger than the input impedance.

Comment: Although it may not make sense at the moment, the voltage is only dropped if you put *more than one resistor in series*.  With only one, it remains the same from point to point.

Comment: @goldilocks that will never make sense.  two resistors in series have an exact equivalent single resistor - quantity is not of consequence; resistance and current are.  crasic's note on current is however accurate.  Inputs are designed to read without altering - by buffering to avoid drawing current.

Comment: @Abel Resistors in series are equivalent to a single resistor in the sense of total resistance and *total* voltage, but the voltage drops across them and is not the same at all points in the circuit as it is with a single resistor: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/511363/52138  That said, the signal at the GPIO input would be the total voltage, unless a separate ground was used (ie., if you connected two resistors between the output and ground, and then connected the input in parallel to the ground, the voltage at the input would be dropped, whereas with one resistor it would not).

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps instead thinking of the effects of both a resistor AND capacitor there?

Note: Doing so directly to your digital outs with a low resistance value can be dangerous to output ports if it cannot handle the resulting current.

When you have long wires, signal loss is not due to just the resistance, it's also that there is some capacitance and also noise picked up.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour for a CMOS input which has an input impedance >10MΩ.

You would have to use a resistor >50MΩ (if you could find such a thing), but this would be regarded as **poor practice**. It is unclear **WHY** you would **WANT** to do this.

NOTE some of the Comments after your Question are incorrect (or misleading).

This Question is not Pi specific.

Comment: I am currently working on a low cost BERT for a personal project, but I am new to using raspberry pi. The reason why I was testing the system with high impedance was to find the threshold value where a GPIO output signal would not be seen by GPIO input. Then using a slightly lower resistance so that the signal could pass but would be susceptible to noise. Thank you for your response, I will avoid using high resistance values in the future on the GPIO header.